# node.js : Getting browser language

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization

Is there any way to get the browser language or something like that to know which language is client using?

I'm talking about node.js =)

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with any other HTTP server, the key here is the [`Accept-Language` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests) that the browser sends with each request. See the [HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) and the [Accept-Language used for locale setting](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales.en.php) W3C FAQ page.

The actual code for reading the value of an HTTP varies depending on exactly which frameworks you're using ("vanilla" Node, Express, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use the famous express server there exists middleware that does the job. [request-language](https://github.com/tinganho/express-request-language) parses the `Accept-Language` header and returns the most preferred language for you:

```
var requestLanguage = require('express-request-language');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(requestLanguage({
  languages: ['en-US', 'zh-CN'],
  cookie: {
    name: 'language',
    options: { maxAge: 24*3600*1000 },
    url: '/languages/{language}'
  }
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.language); // 'en-US'
});
```